# Symfony custom form type, use Options Resolver

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using symfony to create a form for my project.

Based on event, i check if there's an extra color data to add this data to current list .

```
  ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $new_color_value = $data->getColor();

            $form = $event->getForm();

            $form->add('color', ColorType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'invalid_message' => 'La couleur est incorrecte.',
                'other_color_if_exists' => $new_color_value,
                'choice_label' => function ($choice, $key, $value) {
                    return $value;
                },
            ]);
        })
```

My Custom color type :

```
     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $parameters = $this->session->get('parameters');

    $resolver->setDefault('color_from_api', false);
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes('other_color_if_exists', ['null', 'string']);

    $resolver->setDefault('choices', function (Options $options) use ($parameters) {
        if ($options['color_from_api']){
            array_push($parameters['color'], $options['color_from_api']);
        }
        return array_unique($parameters['color']);
    });
}
    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
```

Now i don't use session but this got error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create/pass an option for `'color_from_api'`. Use the `OptionsResolver` to set default `'choices'` with a closure.

In Custom color type :

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
  $parameters = $this->session->get('parameters');

  $resolver->setDefault('color_from_api', false);
  $resolver->setDefault('choices', function (Options $options) use ($parameters) {
    if ($options['color_from_api']){
      array_push($parameters['color'], $options['color_from_api']);
    }

    return array_unique($parameters['color']);
  });

}
```

In controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyEntityType::class, $entity, [
  'color_from_api' => $entity->getColor(),
]);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html#default-values-that-depend-on-another-option

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help , i updated my question based on your solution and i got an error  other_color_if_exists does not exist.

Comment: thank you for your help,  i don't need to use other_color_if_exists option, i just use color_from_api to get the new color